# Link issue when add interpolation

Tags: angular

I have a Angular material table like this one

```
 <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
          <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.id}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nombre </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.nombre}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="apellido">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Apellido </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.apellido}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.email}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="perfil">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Perfil </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.perfil}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="ultimoLogin">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Último Login </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.ultimoLogin}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="activo">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Activo </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.activo}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
              Action
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
              <a href="#/categorias/usuarios/detalle/0"></a>

          </ng-container>
          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
```

It works, but problem starts when I try to add link to `action` column

First I do it as:

```
<a href="#/categorias/usuarios/detalle/0">Link</a>
```

It works correctly, but now I want to get `user.id`(like first column) as a parameter of url, so I do:

```
<a href="'#/categorias/usuarios/detalle/'+{{user.id}}">Link</a>
```

Chrome debbug just returns `<a></a>`:

```
<a>Link</a>
```

So now I try as:

```
 <a href="'#/categorias/usuarios/detalle/'+ user.id">click here</a>
```

But chrome return `user.id` instead value(because it don't have interpolation):

```
<a href="'#/categorias/usuarios/detalle/'+ user.id">click here</a>
```

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong? Why link dissappears when I use interpolation into it? Regards

Comment: Have you tried using ng-href ?
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use use `href` as an attribute?

```
<a [attr.href]="'#/categorias/usuarios/detalle/'+ user.id">Link</a>
```